# 丼: why is "well" also "bowl of food"?

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin

[丼 is an ancient variant of 井](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E3C.htm), which means "well" (as in the water kind). What's curious is that the former seems to also mean "bowl of food", at least in some dictionaries:

汉典:

> **English**
>
> **bowl of food**; well

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%BC#Chinese):

> **Noun**
>
> 1. variant of '井'
> 2. **bowl of food**
> 3. well
> 4. Sound of something falling in a well. Ref: 《集韻》：「丼：投物井中聲。」
> 5. Throwing or littering something to lower position.

Also, this definition survives in Japanese, where 丼 is pronounced "[don](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donburi)".

How did the character get such a seemingly-unrelated definition?

Comment: Well, what does well have to do with well? It happens in other languages too!

Answer (score 3):

This guy *gdfsljz* made a post in the zdic forums I think it quite enlightening [丼 ［汉字资料］](http://bbs.zdic.net/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=19183&pid=668447):

> 粤方言中，此字则解释为粤语中dump的正字。贵州苗族中，有格丼（bong）一地，是苗语中圣地的意思。由于丼字是冷僻字，为了便于宣传，当地政府已将其改为格凸。字典解释[编辑本段]辞海：其一念 jǐng/ㄐㄧㄥˇ，即井字的古字；其二念 dǎn/ㄉㄢˇ，即东西投到井里的声音。语源由来辞典（日本）：丼とは、食物を盛る茶碗より厚手で深い陶制の钵。どんぶり钵。また、どんぶり钵に入れた料理。（大意为：盖饭、比盛食物的碗更深的陶制钵。 丼钵，丼另外放进丼钵的菜。）字源考究[编辑本段]中文丼字来源篆体，因华北平原土厚井深，站在井口俯视，黑洞幽邃，唯见天光投影，圆圆一点。若无这个亮点，那就是没水的涸井，丼了。 日文里，丼字是来源江戸时代，说「悭贪屋（けんどんや）」是一家充满着单份的饮食东西的店，这里使用的钵叫做「悭贪振り钵（けんどんぶりばち）」，于是就把这种钵简称为され「どんぶり钵」（比盛食物的碗更深的陶制钵）。悭贪指吝啬，贪得无厌的的这种意思，所以在「悭贪屋（けんどんや）」吃「どんぶり钵」，可以引申指那些为人又吝啬又欲望深的家伙。日文字典中同样解释说：汉字「丼」是「井」的本字，字面意思为向深井中投入物体时产生的拟音词，日文中采用「丼」作为どんぶり的中文写发更进一步表示了「大碗钵」（的深）。丼与井[编辑本段]《说文解字注》第五篇下的「丼」字小篆，中间有一点，显示《说文》认为「丼」 为井字的初形。《说文》对  的解释为 ：「八家为一  ，象构韩形。…古者伯益初作井 。」， 并认为中间那一点  「象罋」。然而，在李孝定(1965)编纂的《甲骨文字集释》内 ，甲骨文皆作「井」，中间没有一点。在已知的卜辞中，此字皆用于「井方」、「帚井」等处，都没有用来指涉水井。至于周代的金文，根据周法高(1982)编纂的《金文诂林》与 《金文诂林补》，就区分为「井」与「丼」两形。井字在很多地方可以通假作「刑」或 「型」，也用来作为地名或人名。「井」和「丼」两字截然有别，但都找不到一种用法是指涉「水井」的。根据全广镇(1989) 《两周金文通假字研究》（页205 ）与吴其昌(1991) 《金文世族谱》（卷二页五至六、卷一页十八至十九），中间有一点的「丼」，皆与姜姓之奠 (郑)    氏有关 ，例如  壶之「丼公」、  鼎之「丼叔」。中间无一点的井字，与「邢」字相通 ，受封者是周公之后，为姬姓 ，例如麦鼎之「井侯」。虽然在甲骨文卜辞与钟鼎铭文中，都找不到作为水井之用的井字，但是《说文》也确指「丼」字是「井」字的初形。我们还不知道 ，究竟是在周代分化为二字，或是水井的「丼」在甲骨文里本来中间就有一点 ，只是因没有用在地名或人名上，所以才未在卜辞中留下记录。如果是后者，那有可能「井」字的原义就是「效法」或「规范」 ，并由此引申出「阱」、「刑」、「型」等字。 丼字如果是从井字衍申而来，本来或许是写作「丼」，从水从井。此字见于甲骨文，但不见于《说文》，在后来的《集韵》与《玉篇》中，此字解作「小水」，或假借作「阱」。可能是再由「丼」简化作「丼」，中间那一点并非如《说文》所说的是「象罋」。这只是个猜想，目前还没有直接的证据来证实或否证。 日本盖饭的来历[编辑本段]曼谷王朝自1728年在湄南河东岸另辟新都建朝至今，湄南河曼谷西岸一段就被统称为吞武里（Thonburi ）地区，就像上海的浦东一样。曼谷王朝之前，泰国处于有着中国血统的郑王（King Taksin）统治下的吞武里王国时代。据说那个时候，吞武里王国出口了很多瓷器到日本。盛盖浇饭用的盖碗往往来自吞武里王国，所以日本人就把盖碗饭叫成了Thonburi饭。由于日语人发音常常T、D不分的缘故，Thonburi 在日本人口中成了Donburi，后来又简称为Don了

As it comes from Japanese, the Japanese meaning of the character was, seemingly, originally to do with food.

Quite a messy history, really.

Comment: The last part about Thonburi is doubtful.  They didn't export porcelain to Japan - that's just wrong.

Comment: Could you please summarise the text in english?

Comment: My Japanese is not the best but the line, "丼とは、食物を盛る茶碗より厚手で深い陶制の钵" seems to suggest that '丼' is a vessel or container that is used to hold food and is thicker and deeper than the bowl used to serve tea made from porcelain?

Comment: @congusbongus uh, yuh, I'll get to that later,

Answer (score 0):

"Well" and "The sound of something thrown into a well" are the original Chinese meaning of "丼".

The meaning of "Bowl of food" is adopted from Japan, though such usage is rare outside Japanese restaurants.